# How to test sequelize query (where) logic?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write unit tests which will test if the search query is right In other words if the logic written in `where` statement is returning expected results.

```
 async function search(some_data){
   return Event.findOne({
    where: {
      id: 123435,
      [Op.or]: [
        days: {
            [Op.overlap]: some_data.days,
        },
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            startTime: {
              [Op.gt]: some_data.start1,
            },
            endTime: {
              [Op.lt]:some_data.end1,
            },
          },
          {
            startTime: {
              [Op.lt]: some_data.start2,
              [Op.lt]: some_data.end2,
            },
            endTime: {
              [Op.gt]: some_data.end2,
              [Op.gt]: some_data.start2,
            },
          },
        ],
    ],
  },
})};
```

I need to test the result for different inputs.
I don't want to convert this test into integration test and use the original db, so I used `sequelize-mock` lib, but this returns only the result that I've defined and does not run the real query.

Answer (score 0):

To test that your method is called with the correct parameters, you will need to use dependency injetion and a library to "spy" on your `findOne` method. In the example below, I am using [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.2.1/spies/)

```
// app.js
// Note that "Event" must be used an argument in order to mock it out
async function search(Event, some_data) {
  return Event.findOne({
    where: {
      id: 123435
    }
  })
}
```

If your test file:

```
// your test file
const app = require('./app');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const EventMock = {
  findOne: sinon.spy()
};

describe('search', () => {
  it('should call with the right parameters', () => {
    const some_data = {};
    search(EventMock, some_data);

    assert(EventMock.findOne.calledWith({
      where: {
        id: 123435
      }
    }))
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not answering the question. It only tests the passed arguments to the `findOne` method but not if the `where` logic yields the expected query result.